# Remote connection to a folder

Tags: nas, remote, sharing

I have a nas with a shared folder and I want to connect (and work) remotely on the file of this folder.

I'm using now ftp, but for editing I must first download file and then upload, and is a "little problem" and waste of time.

Then is possibile to connect folder like is a local folder and work on doc, pdf etc.. file ?

EDIT

Sorry for my english...

On server with shared folder there is linux debian installed, and client have windows installed

I must share the folder in a WAN and client must work on document directly, not downloading and uploading, like is a LAN

I hope I was clear :)

Comment: You say .... **"I'm using now ftp,.... Then is possibile to connect folder like is a local folder a..."** Well why note create a SHARE of this folder and then rather than connecting to it via FTP, connect to it via SMB\CIFS? It sounds like you need help setting up folder in your system so it can be accessible via this method but you've worded this in a way that people can easily not understand what you are asking for exactly. Please [edit] your question and word it more clearly if you can and also tell the specs of your setup such as Linux flavor, Windows version, and all those details missing

Answer (score 0):

You need install Samba server on your linux, add samba user, share folder with rights for created samba user. Install OpenVPN server (or other VPN server) on linux, and client on windows, forward VPN ports from WAN to linux IP, configure OpenVPN server and client, connect from windows and use files...